# Getting "IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type" When trying to create SpringFramework Bean using object that is not an Entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

In the application I am working on, I have several Entity classes. For example:

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Column
    private String columnA;

    public String getColumnA() {
        return columnA;
    }

    public void setColumnA(String columnA) {
        this.columnA= columnA;
    }
}
```

I have accompanying Repositories:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
    Person findByPersonID(Long id);
}
```

Then I utilize the repositories like so:

```
@Autowired
private PersonRepository personRepository;
```

I have several Entities (e.g., Person, Status, Training, Benefits, etc.)

I am needing to make a very specialized report query to the database that uses multiple joins across multiple tables. I have the query working in MySQL Workbench.

So, I created a new Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ReportRepository extends CrudRepository<Report, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT ...")
    List<Report> queryReportData(String columnA, String columnB, String columnC, ...);
}
```

Where Report is just a POJO with the fields I need:

```
public class Report {
    private String columnA;
    private String columnB;
    // etc ...
}
// Getters and Setters here
```

My issue is when I try to use the repository like so:

```
@Autowired
private ReportRepository reportRepository;
```

I get run-time errors:

> creating bean with name 'genController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'reportRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reportRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.me.Report

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reportRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.me.Report

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.me.Report

Where genController is:

```
@RestController
public class GenController {
}
```

Granted, Report.java is not an actual `@Entity` as it is not "really" in the database.

So, am I going about this completely wrong, or am I kind of on the right path?

What do I need to do in order to get the data I need using my custom, cross table, query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if Report is not an entity, you can not do that. if you are using a native query already, you can just put this method into an entity repositort. Such as person. and Autowire the personRepository instead report repository

Comment: I didn't know I could do that. I thought Person.java had to go with PersonRepository.java, Status.java had to go with StatusReport.java, and so on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `Report` object needs to be annotated as `@Entity` so it will be picked up by JPA

Without that annotation, Spring, as you can see in your stack trace, throws an exception when it tries to construct an instance of a `CrudRepository` because `Report` is not a managed object